# Kotlin callbacks OnClickListener from Recyclerview for multiple buttons

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, lambda, callback

I'm really confused about how the Kotlin lambdas work, specifically with click listeners.  I had something that was working to do a single ViewModel function in my MainFragment but now I want multiple buttons on my adapter that do different things.  At first I thought I would just have to pass all the necessary information including IDs for the different buttons to the callback then do a switch statement in my main fragment that does the appropriate ViewModel functions.  As soon as I changed my input parameters the adapter no longer accepted my OnClickListener argument.

First I'll show the old OnClickListener that was working.

**ItemAdapter**

```
class ItemAdapter(private val context: Context, private val onClickListener: OnClickListener) : ListAdapter<SongWithRatings, ItemAdapter.SongViewHolder>(SongsComparator())
{

    lateinit var isVisible: BooleanArray

    override fun onCurrentListChanged(
        previousList: List<SongWithRatings>,
        currentList: List<SongWithRatings>
    ) {
        super.onCurrentListChanged(previousList, currentList)
        if(previousList.size != currentList.size) {
            isVisible = BooleanArray(itemCount)
            isVisible.fill(element = false)
        }
    }

    class SongViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val textView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.item_title)
        val textViewBpm: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.bpm)
        val lastPlayed: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.lastPlayed)

        //new rating code 11/27/2021
        val ratingBar: SeekBar = view.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar)
        val ratingLabel: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.ratingLabel)
        val button: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.submitRating)

        //expandable view 3/27/2022
        val titleView: LinearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.titleView)
        val expand: ConstraintLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.expand)

        //fragment launch buttons
        val moreButton: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.moreButton)
        val rateButton: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.rateButton)

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SongViewHolder {
        // create a new view
        val adapterLayout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)
        return SongViewHolder(adapterLayout)

    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SongViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = getItem(position)
        //temporary code for initial rating
        val initialRating = item.recentPerformanceRating()
        var newRating = 0


        holder.textView.text = item.song.songTitle
        holder.textViewBpm.text = context.resources.getString(R.string.BPM,item.song.bpm)
        holder.ratingLabel.setBackgroundColor(getStatusColor(item.recentPerformanceRating()))
        //holder.imageView.setImageResource(item.imageResourceID)
        holder.ratingLabel.text = context.resources.getString(R.string.Rating, initialRating )
        holder.lastPlayed.text = item.lastPlayedString()

        //rating bar functionality
        holder.ratingBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar, rating: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
                holder.ratingLabel.text  = context.resources.getString(R.string.Rating, rating)
                newRating = rating

            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {}
            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {}
        })


        //Performance Rating button functionality
        holder.button.setOnClickListener{
            onClickListener.onClick(item.song.songTitle, newRating)
                
        }
        holder.moreButton.setOnClickListener {  }

    class OnClickListener(val clickListener: (songTitle: String, newRating: Int) -> Unit) {
        fun onClick(songTitle: String,newRating: Int) = clickListener(songTitle, newRating)
    }

}
```

From **MainFragment**

```
 val recyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view)
        val adapter = ItemAdapter(requireContext(),
            ItemAdapter.OnClickListener { songTitle, newRating ->
                songViewModel.insertRating( Rating(System.currentTimeMillis(),songTitle,songViewModel.artistName, newRating )) }
        )
```

Like I said, this all worked fine until I tried to use the **OnClickListener** with a **SongsWithRatings** parameter.

Am I even close here or do I have to redo my whole interface between the adapter, fragment and ViewModel?

Answer (score 4):

You just have to make use of Interface for the purpose of providing listeners to the Fragment .

Step 1: Create an Interface Class.

```
interface ItemClickListener{
//You can include the parameters into the functions which you wish to be associated with the button. Suppose I want Title on Click of more Button, then I will pass it as a parameter

   fun onButtonClick(val item : SongsWithRating)
   fun onMoreButtonClicked(val title : String)
}
```

Step 2 : Create a listener variable in your adapter and call the functions in the onClick function of the respective buttons

```
class ItemAdapter(private val context: Context) : ListAdapter<SongWithRatings, ItemAdapter.SongViewHolder>(SongsComparator())
{

  var listener : ItemClickListener ?= null

  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SongViewHolder, position: Int) {
     val item = getItem(position)
     
    //Calling buttonClick and passing the function defined in the interface 
     along with the parameters
 
     holder.button.setOnClickListener{
       listener?.onButtonClick(item)
     } 

     //Similarly for morebutton 
     holder.moreButton.SetOnClickListener{
        listener?.onMoreButtonClicked(item.song.songTitle)
     }
   }
    
}
```

Step 3 : Now the final Step : Go to the fragment wherein the recyclerView is implemented

```
//Extent the Fragment with the Interface and override the methods 
class Fragment : Fragment(), ItemClickListener{

 //define Adapter and attach the listener
 val adapter = ItemAdapter(requireContext()
 adapter.listener = this
 
}
```

You are good to go

Comment: Where and how do I interact with the view model then?   In this case, songViewModel

Comment: I'm using lambdas as opposed to the interface.

Comment: If you are following the Clean Architecture / MVVM then you should communicate the adapter to the fragment and then pass it to the ViewModel or else you can make use of DataBinding but then you need to evaluate the logic to suit your needs

Comment: Interface provide better readability as opposed to lambdas considering your UseCase. But if you need to implement it in lambda format then consider passing the interface itself as a parameter to the adapter